# Multiple distros refuse to connect to wired internet

Tags: networking, fedora, manjaro

I have both a Fedora and Manjaro live USB. If I plug these into my laptop, both can successfully connect to my WiFi network. If I walk over to my desktop, take out its ethernet cable, and plug it in my laptop, both distros can successfully connect to the wired network connection.

Now, the problem: if I plug the same ethernet cable in my desktop, neither distro can make a connection to the internet. Pinging 8.8.8.8 returns `network unreachable`. I can’t connect to my router at `192.168.1.1` either.

Edit: turning off my computer, then restarting my router fixes the problem. However, after booting back into Windows, shutting down and booting back to Linux, the problem returns. Turning my PSU off and on again also seems to fix the issue. Booting into Windows seems to do something to the internet connection, but I have no idea what.

I have no idea what is causing this. How do I figure out the cause?

Comment: did you configure your desktop as a router ? (I expect nowdays cable will auto-crossover)

Comment: Hi, I did not configure anything. I plugged in the USB stick in my desktop, booted to desktop, and started Firefox without touching any settings. The same steps work on my laptop.

Comment: @Archemar your comment about auto-crossover struck a chord with me so I rebooted my router. The connection worked again. Then I booted into Windows again, and rebooted back to Fedora, and I lose connection again. Any idea what’s going on?

Comment: strange you should get an IP from router, in fact all distros should get the same IP, and so a connection to internet.

Comment: you never say if windows has network connectivity

Comment: is the linux distro spoofing the MAC address?

Comment: Ah sorry @jsotola. Yes, Windows has network activity.